# Standard way to report covariates with multiple levels in regression table?

Tags: r, regression, reporting

Is there a standard way to report regression coefficients for control variables that have multiple levels?  For example, I have a control variable that tracks a participant's "State" -- that contains 50 levels.  Reporting each of these in a regression summary table generates a very long report.  I can't recall seeing such long tables in other publications, so I'm wondering how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you "reporting" this?  In a paper submission?  If so, you can truncate the table for the main body, and see APPENDIX for entire list.